calculate the Euler characteristic using a triangulation
I am trying to calculate the Euler characteristics of different surfaces, which are squares with holes, triangles, etc. I see very clearly how to make the triangulations, but when they give me a parameterization I do not understand how to proceed because I don't see triangles in any way, an example would be the parameterization $z^2=x^2+y^2, z>0$ (the cone of revolution of 1 sheet without the vertex) in the region $z\geq1, z\leq3$.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The surface $z^2=x^2+y^2$ in the retion $1<z<3$ is noncompact, so any triangulation will have infinitely many vertices, edges, and faces. This, perhaps, is not what you intended.

Yes, I forgot the equals in the less and greter

The Euler Characteristic for surfaces will only work with things topologically equivalent to a sphere or a genus-g torus (including PL surfaces such as polyhedra), or slight extensions such as removing points or adding boundary components. Assuming we focus only on the compact case, you're essentially asking for a recognition algorithm for surfaces, which is known depending on the data of the presentation you're given.

It's hard to answer your question in the level of generality that you formulate it.
But given any particular example, you can perhaps use your mathematical knowledge to figure out how to work with the surface, and to recognize it, enough so that you can calculate with it.
For your particular example, you can recognize this surface as the graph of the function
$$z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}, \qquad 1 \le x^2 + y^2 \le 3
$$
The domain of this function is an annulus in the $x,y$ plane whose inner boundary is the circle of radius $1$ and whose outer boundary is the circle of radius $\sqrt{3}$. Like any continuous function in topology, the graph of that function is homeomorphic to its domain. And, of course, Euler characteristic is a topological invariant: the Euler characteristics of two homeomorphic spaces are equal.
The Euler characteristic you need to calculate is therefore equal to the Euler characteristic of that annulus in the plane.
Can you take it from there?

Yes! Thank you so much
